# How can I refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 21 to the 15 allowed?

Tags: java, sonarqube

```java
/** @param  e */
    private void doActionForUldProfileRecordGrid(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if ((uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid() != null) && (source == uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getSelectionModel()))
        {
            try
            {
                if (uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid() != null)
                {
                    UldProfileRec data = (UldProfileRec) getDataVector().elementAt(uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid()
                            .getActiveRow());

                    if ((data != null) && Str.isNotEmpty(data.contourGroup))
                    {
                        ContourGroup contourGroup = ContourGroupServiceCallUtil.getContourGroup(data.contourGroup);

                        if ((uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getActiveRow()
                                == (uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getRowCount() - 1)))
                        {
                            data = new UldProfileRec();
                            getDataVector().addElement(data);
                        }

                        if (contourGroup != null)
                        {
                            data.setBaseWeight(contourGroup.defaultWeight());
                            data.setBaseVolume(contourGroup.defaultVolume());
                            data.deck(contourGroup.getDeckDescription());
                        }
                    }

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        setWeightVolume(data, data.position());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (VerifyException ve)
            {
                LOGGER.warn(ve.getLocalizedMessage(), ve);
            }
        } // end if
    }
```

Comment: what's your question, besides posting your homework question?

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor you code and separate out isolated logic into separate smaller methods, this will help you in two fronts:

1. It will make the code more modular and maintainable.
2. Smaller methods are easier to test and reduce the possibilities of introducing bugs in future.

And, as a by-product the cognitive complexity of the methods will also reduce.

For example :

From this method :

```
private void doActionForUldProfileRecordGrid(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if ((uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid() != null) && (source == uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getSelectionModel()))
        {
            try
            {
                if (uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid() != null)
                {
                    UldProfileRec data = (UldProfileRec) getDataVector().elementAt(uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid()
                            .getActiveRow());

                    if ((data != null) && Str.isNotEmpty(data.contourGroup))
                    {
                        **ContourGroup contourGroup = ContourGroupServiceCallUtil.getContourGroup(data.contourGroup);

                        if ((uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getActiveRow()
                                == (uldProfileTab.getRecordsGrid().getRowCount() - 1)))
                        {
                            data = new UldProfileRec();
                            getDataVector().addElement(data);
                        }

                        if (contourGroup != null)
                        {
                            data.setBaseWeight(contourGroup.defaultWeight());
                            data.setBaseVolume(contourGroup.defaultVolume());
                            data.deck(contourGroup.getDeckDescription());
                        }**
                    }

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        setWeightVolume(data, data.position());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (VerifyException ve)
            {
                LOGGER.warn(ve.getLocalizedMessage(), ve);
            }
        } // end if
```

You can refactor the highlighted part, can move it into a separate method.